# Unexpected dominant pole in active-RC circuit

Tags: capacitor, analog, filter, circuit-analysis, transfer-function

Consider this active-RC circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fn6lED.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

it should exactly realize the RLC high-pass filter with one zero:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fl7bYV.png)</sup>

It realizes the same equations and so the same transfer function. This model has been used to obtain an analog, elliptic, high-pass filter with a low (about 0.01 Hz) cutoff frequency.

After a simulation (with negative resistor values, supposing that they are realizable), the active-RC transfer function seems to be the same as the RLC-prototype, but with a difference: a new and unexpected pole at a very high frequency, about 10 GHz.

After \$ f = 10 \ \mathrm{GHz} \$, the transfer function decreases regularly at 20 dB/decade and it is no more flat as it should be.

The opamps were realized through ideal VCVS generators (Voltage-Controlled Voltage Source), with a high gain (\$ 10^9 \$ at least).

If the order of the filter is increased, the pole **decreases is frequency**. For an eight-order circuit, it is at about 100 Hz!! And it is intolerable.

The RLC-prototype used for the 8th order circuit is

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZPve0.png)</sup>

And it does not have any 100 Hz pole, despite of its active-RC realization (I don't draw it for shortness).

The simulator used is Spectre (from Cadence) and the values for the RLC prototype are taken from "A. B. Williams and F. J. Taylor, Electronic filter design, 3rd edition, McGraw-Hill, 1995" (both for the 3rd and 8th order filters).

So, are there in the topology of the active-RC some elements that could be generate such a pole? Or are there some undesired parasitics automatically inserted by that simulator?

Google didn't show anything useful.

Comment: The continuous decrease of the function (rather than being flat) is caused, of course, by the real opamp models with an open-loop gain that goes down with rising frequencies.

Comment: No, the opamp have been modeled with ideal vcvs generators, with a gain of \$ 10^9 \$.

Comment: Check the default setting on your simulator. It may naturally add parasitic capacitance on each node. Micro cap does this and a few fempto farads at ten gig is not ignorable

Comment: V3out is the output node of an IDEAL opamp (infinite gain, and zero r,out). Hence, this output must go down to zero for very large frequencies.

Comment: @LvW  -- doesn't an ideal opamp have infinite bandwidth?

Comment: Yes - of course. But with a cap in the feedback path and very large frequencies the output always goes to zero.

Comment: @LvW You're right, but the load is \$ R_L \$ and it is present in **both** the circuit, the RLC prototype and the active-RC realization. So, the opamp is not without load.

Comment: @Andyaka I will check for parasitic capacitance, even if I think they are not included by default.

Comment: @LvW The frequency response of an integrator always go to zero for high frequency, but I have updated my question: this pole decreases its frequency by increasing the order of the filter.

Comment: How sure are you of your transformation between the two figures?  Seems like an obvious point to check.

Comment: @ScottSeidman I omitted the equations and the procedure for shortness. Anyway, I am sure that the first circuit realizes the second; the equations and the state variables are the same for both the circuits and I checked it many times.

Comment: @BowPark, it does not matter if the opamps have finite load resistors - the integrator outputs goes to zero for rising frequencies. But - a general question: Where did the active circuit comes from? I feel rather familiar with active filters, but I have never seen a circuit like this (with negative resistors). Is it a special form of "leapfrog topology"? Are you forced to use this topology?

Comment: @BowPark -- if everything were working the way you think it should be working, it would be working!!  I suggest working your way up from a simpler problem, as with most debugging paths.

Comment: @LvW Yes an opamp output goes to zero due to the feedback capacitor, but this is a whole circuit which should work overall as a high-pass. The active-RC circuit is the penultimate step for the synthesis of a switched-capacitor circuit (where negative resistors are easily realized): it is exactly a leapfrog, you're right. And yes, I am forced to use this technique.

Comment: @ScottSeidman I thought this already was the "simpler" problem, it is a 3rd order filter. Maybe I could simply realize a single order high pass filter.

Comment: @BowPark, independent on the overall circuits topology, the output voltage of an integrator circuit based on ideal opamps (r,out=0) must approach zero volts for rising frequencies! With or without loads. In reality, there are no active circuits (and also no real passive circuits) which approach a finite output voltage for rising frequencies.

Comment: @LvW Ok. But this is an ideal simulation, which should behave different. Anyway, the fact is that rising the order of the filter, the pole decreases its frequency: can this simply be due to the opamp-RC integrators?

Comment: @BowPark, I recommend to check if a change of the ideal opamp gain alters the unwanted pole. This would help to identify the source of your problem.

Comment: @LvW Good advice, already done. Tried several values from 1k to 1T (now it is 1G), without any significant changes.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you worry about such a thing? It's a LF circuit. It won't do anything substantial at 10GHz - at least not anything you have any control over. It's all determined by the parasitics there. It's a case of a garbage result - simply ignore the response past 100MHz or so, depending on the speed of op-amps you're using.

Comment: I don't think it is determined by parasitic capacitances, which should not even be present in that fully-ideal active-RC circuit. I updated my question: raising the order of the circuit, the pole decreases its frequency and it is at about 100 Hz for an 8-order high-pass filter realized with the same procedure. Do you notice anything in the topology that could originate the pole?

Comment: @BowPark What I meant was that in a real circuit, the parasitics would determine the response, not whatever the simulator told you, or whatever you put into the circuit. At those frequencies, the shape of the traces is very, very important :) You need to try tell us exactly what 8 pole circuit did you simulate (I see none), and exactly in what software. I'd try it first in something other than CircuitLab first. For all I know, the values you use in your 8 pole circuit are bad. Where did you get the values?

Comment: Please, read the end of the question: I have updated it with some more informations. The values are correct, in fact the RLC prototypes have a high-pass behaviour, without any 10 GHz pole, both in the 3rd order and in the 8th order case. The 8th order circuit is built with the same procedure; it has simply the L1, L2, L3, C2 cell repeated 3 times and then a capacitor C8 before the load.

Comment: @BowPark Do you really expect us to have to look somewhere for the values you used for your filter and for the actual circuit that you've used? As it is, we can't even simulate it in CircuitLab. It's really on you to try to simulate it in multiple simulators and compare the behavior. You should only ask such a question when you verify that multiple simulators all agree on the behavior.